# How to stop Webpack minifying HTML?

Tags: webpack

I have read the [part of the Webpack documentation](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md) that explains why Webpack will minify HTML when setting a loader using the `module.loaders` syntax. But I can't find anywhere that explains how to stop this. I am using `pug-loader` and `html-webpack-plugin` to process my templates, but Webpack always spits them out with the HTML minified.

How can I stop this?

```
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  use: 'pug-loader'
}

new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: 'Home',
  filename: 'index.html',
  template: './src/index.pug',
  inject: 'head',
  chunks: ['app'],
  hash: true
}),
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This issue](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/issues/377) may help you.

```
loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.pug$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: "pug-html",
      query: {
        pretty: true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: That is using the `pug-html-loader` plug in.

Comment: Although, that option is also available for `pug-loader` and works, so thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There's an option for html-webpack-plugin. `minify: false`. Have you tried adding that?

https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#configuration

Comment: I have tried that, the files in the `dist` folder are still minified though.

Answer (score 3):

Below command works for both `npm run dev` and `npm run prod`

```
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.pug$/,
            use: [
                'html-loader?minimize=false', 
                'pug-html-loader?pretty=true'
            ]
        }]
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
rules: [{
    test: /\.pug$/,
    use: [
        {
           loader: 'html-loader',
           options: {
                minimize: false
           }
        },
        {
            loader: 'pug-html-loader',
            options: {
                pretty: true
            }
        }
    ],
}],
```

Comment: Does this work even with `optimization: { minimizer ... }` in production too?